# Is the Google Play Services Lib compiled with my app?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm a little confuse about how Google Play Services is compiled/used by device.
I have read that Google Play Services is updated on devices via the Play Store.
I have also read that peoples app increasing in size due to the Google Play Services lib being compiled into their app. 
These 2 points seem to be in conflict to me so maybe I am misunderstanding something.
So:
1: Is google play services functionality run externally from outside of apps?
2: Is the Google Play Services actually compiled into apps?
3: If both above are true which version is used?
4: If I have a lib jar that uses GPS and the main App also uses GPS will GPS be included twice?

Thanks for any info that can bring more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1: Is google play services functionality run externally from outside of apps?

**The call originates from your app and is run in the name of your app (permission wise).** However the call is received by the Google Play services package and the code executed is also contained within Play services.

> 2: Is the Google Play Services actually compiled into apps?

**No**, Google Play services is installed separately on your device. **The Play services interface however is compiled into your app.**

> 3: If both above are true which version is used?

**The code from "Google Play services" app is always used.** And it is mostly backwards compatible (so older interface can safely use newer Play services).

> 4: If I have a lib jar that uses GPS and the main App also uses GPS will GPS be included twice?

The compiler should warn you and abort if those .jar differ in size (meaning they are different version). If both are the same, then the project compiles and **the GPS interface is included only once**. This is OK, because you can't have multiple classes with the same full name.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Services is a system app that is installed on every phone with the Play Store. It handles communications with Google's servers and coordinates requests, handle caching, etc across all applications requiring access to the services it includes.

What you include in your application is the Google Play Services library which handles your app connecting to the Google Play Services app, forwarding requests from your app on through the Google Play Services app (and ultimately onto Google where appropriate to fulfill the request).

Therefore the flow goes:

```
your app -> Google Play Services library -> Google Play Services app -> Google
```

Like any library, only one version exists in the final APK.